# What is the domain and codomain of a transfer function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laplace-transform, control-theory

Let's say I have the transfer function-

$\textbf{H}(j\omega)=\cfrac{1}{1+j\omega RC}$

Where does this function map to and from, and can it be plotted visually?

Comment: $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: To those who voted to put the question on hold: I'm disappointed. Just because you aren't particularly interested in control as an application of complex analysis doesn't mean it is "off topic". OP's question was perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off looking at the transfer function in the $s$-domain where it looks like
$$
H(s) = \frac{1}{1+RCs}
$$
From the Laplace transformation you know that $0\leq s<\infty$ and from the range of $s$ you get $0 < H \leq 1$. Your version of the transfer function is obtained when you use the substitution $s\mapsto j\omega$ which only works for a linear system (well, so do transfer functions themselves, but that's beside the point). This is essentially a rotation of $s$ onto the imaginary axis and renaming it frequency, and the magnitude of this complex function is the system gain as a function of the signal frequency.

How do you plot it visually? That's basically the majority of classical controller analysis in the frequency domain! Take a look at these two wikipedia pages for a start:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_plot

Bode and Nyquist plots are a staple of classical control and extremely useful in real controller designs. Also less frequently is used the Nichols plot

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichols_plot

Comment: Ah ok, for some reason, my textbook tries to explain transfer functions by looking at a circuit and usually using voltage or current division and complex impedences to find $\cfrac{\textbf{Y}(\omega)}{\textbf{X}(\omega)}$ and then just says 'oh by the way, you can substitute $s=j\omega$' without even mentioning the Laplace transfrom

Comment: I see. I took my first control class in a Mech Eng department and the Prof. just gave us this as a fact by *fiat*. The worst part about those approaches is you don't even understand that in the most general circumstance $s = \sigma + j\omega$, where $\sigma$ is the Neper frequency and tells you the rate at which the function decays. The frequency domain techniques all assume you are forcing with a sinusoidal input, thus assumes no decay in the signal.